# ELK visualisation with log time

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I am working ELK and apart of my requirement, I am loading my application logs to elk from a log file which is writing my application logs.

I need to index the time in the log file as one field. (sometimes I need to load old log file, so that elk time may not be used for analysis)

Now I need to create a line chart (visualization), with the y-axis as the time field.

1 - Howto configure these index in logstash

2 - Is there any calendar plugin available to select the date range by the end user to get date range wise visualization.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it when i back to this task, working some other stuffs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Influxdb output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-influxdb.html) or [statsd output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-statsd.html) for logstash for that.

From InfluxDB website,

> InfluxDB is used as a data store for any use case involving large
>   amounts of timestamped data, including DevOps monitoring, application
>   metrics, IoT sensor data, and real-time analytics. Conserve space on
>   your machine by configuring InfluxDB to keep data for a defined length
>   of time, automatically expiring & deleting any unwanted data from the
>   system. InfluxDB also offers a SQL-like query language for interacting
>   with data.

From Statsd logstash plugin page,

> statsd is a network daemon for aggregating statistics, such as
>   counters and timers, and shipping over UDP to backend services, such
>   as Graphite or Datadog. The general idea is that you send metrics to
>   statsd and every few seconds it will emit the aggregated values to the
>   backend. Example aggregates are sums, average and maximum values,
>   their standard deviation, etc. This plugin makes it easy to send such
>   metrics based on data in Logstash events.